# how to allow the user to pass the flag to any parameter in the shell script

Tags: bash, shell, arguments, sh, flags

In all the shell script tutorials I've seen, they show how to collect the flag for a specific parameter (ex: pass the flag only in the first parameter and then check its value with `case $1 in`), but I've seen several scripts that allow you pass the flags in any position, like, allow you to pass the flag as second, third or fourth parameter, etc...

ex:

instead the script just check argument 1 for flags:

`script.sh -flag arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5`

I want to allow the user to pass the flags in any position of the arguments:

`script.sh arg1 arg2 -flag -flag arg5`

Is there any way to do this? to allow me to pass this flag and detect that the parameter is a flag, without having to tell my code that it is only allowed to accept flags at specific positions? maybe a loop solves this problem?

Comment: GNU `getopt` allows you do to this. Here's the [canonical bash example script](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/getopt-parse.bash)

Comment: You can loop on your arguments (`$@`) and process the first arg (`$1`).  After processing the first one, call `shift` to remove it.  So the next loop will again process `$1`, which is now the second argument you put when you called the script.  And so on...